# change xml element text using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, text, element

Given a parsed xml string:

```
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)
```

How would you change an element's text from 'hats':

```
>>> tree.find("path/to/element").text
>>> 'hats'
```

to 'cats'?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simply set the [`.text` attribute value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text):

```
In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

In [2]: root = ET.fromstring("<root><elm>hats</elm></root>")

In [3]: elm = root.find(".//elm")

In [4]: elm.text
Out[4]: 'hats'

In [5]: elm.text = 'cats'

In [6]: ET.tostring(root)
Out[6]: '<root><elm>cats</elm></root>'
```

Comment: So simple, it's a shame the docs entry for "text" has [nothing written there](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text). It could at least mention it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et # import the elementtree module
root = et.fromstring(command_request) # fromString parses xml from string to an element, command request can be xml request string
root.find("cat").text = "dog" #find the element tag as cat and replace it with the string to be replaced.
et.tostring(root) # converts the element to a string
```

cheers