# Modify xml element when having similar names in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I need to modify the parameters of a function in xml file with ElementTree while the elements have similar names. In this example I want to change only the number 2 and keep the others. Is it possible?

```
<Model>
    <Function>
      <param>x</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>2</param>
      <param>5</param>
     </Function>
</Model>
```

Comment: you can use xpath to select the correct `param`-element based on the value `2` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198253/xpath-how-to-select-elements-based-on-their-value)). alternatively you could also select the third occurrence of `param` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element)). once you have the element, use `ElementTree`s capabilities to change the text (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244271/change-xml-element-text-using-xml-etree-elementtree)).

Answer (score 0):

Just one example, though a little late.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
html = '''
<Model>
    <Function>
      <param>x</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>2</param>
      <param>5</param>
     </Function>
</Model>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# Use text 2
param = doc.getElementByText('2',tag='param')
# Use index
param = doc.selects('param')[2]
param.setContent('Modified')
print(doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<Model>
    <Function>
      <param>x</param>
      <param>type</param>
      <param>Modified</param>
      <param>5</param>
     </Function>
</Model>
```