# How to update the value in a xml with sub child elements

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to update the value of the 2 sub-child elements mentioned below from the given XML.

1. <stringProp name="filename">**language-preferences__GET.jtl**</stringProp>
2. <subresults>**false**</subresults>

```xml
</hashTree>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="false">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>false</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>false</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>true</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <hostname>true</hostname>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <sampleCount>true</sampleCount>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="StatVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Aggregate Report" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>false</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>true</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">language-preferences__GET.jtl</stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
```

I have written the code below to reach the child elements of `ResultCollector`. However, I am not able figure out the better way of navigate through the multiple sub child elements.

```py
    tree = ET.parse(jmx_path)
    aggregate_samplers = tree.findall('.//ResultCollector[@testname="Aggregate Report"]')
    active_aggregate_samplers = [active_aggregate_sampler for active_aggregate_sampler in aggregate_samplers
                                 if active_aggregate_sampler.attrib['enabled'] == 'true']
    for active_sampler in active_aggregate_samplers:
        for child in active_sampler:
            if child.tag == 'objProp':
                # < update **subresults** value as true>
            elif child.attrib['name'] == 'filename':
                child.text = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '_' + child.text // new file name
                # < update **filename** value as c82fa39b-5079-4838-b17c-fdf85f49fd5f_language-preferences__GET.jtl>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change xml element text using xml.etree.ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244271/change-xml-element-text-using-xml-etree-elementtree)

Comment: partially. However, I want to know if we have to loop around for each sub child element

Comment: From your example, you should only have to loop over `active_aggregate_samplers`. You can use `find`, etc. on any tag node, not just root, and it'll be relative to that node.

Comment: your suggestion s worked.

`subresult = active_sampler.find("./objProp/value/subresults")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Your example xml snippet has no root element!

**Answer:**
If the xml is correct you can find a list of your interested tags with `findall()`, see the [doc](https://docs.python.domainunion.de/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Than change the text or attribute content of the related list elements:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("hashTree.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

subres_list = root.findall(".//subresults")
for subres in subres_list:
    subres.text = "true" # your new text for the list elements

stringP_list = root.findall(".//stringProp")
for stringP in stringP_list:
    stringP.text = "c82fa39b-5079-4838-b17c-fdf85f49fd5f_language-preferences__GET.jtl”
```

You can also change individually tags of the list with the index(), e.g.:

```
stringP_list[1].text = "new text" # use list index
```

Answer (score 0):

Final working code

````
    tree = ET.parse(jmx_path)

    aggregate_samplers = tree.findall('.//ResultCollector[@testname="Aggregate Report"]')
    active_aggregate_samplers = [active_aggregate_sampler for active_aggregate_sampler in aggregate_samplers
                                 if active_aggregate_sampler.attrib['enabled'] == 'true']
    for active_sampler in active_aggregate_samplers:
        subresult = active_sampler.find("./objProp/value/subresults")
        if subresult.text == 'true':
            subresult.text = 'false'
        filename = active_sampler.find("./stringProp[@name='filename']")
        filename.text = os.path.join(jlt_path, str(uuid.uuid4()) + '_' + filename.text)
        
    ```
````